# MessageBox.Show called from backgound worker with the handle of the main UI thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.5, messagebox

I have this code:

```
public void Blah(IWin32Window _this)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item_quantity; i++)
    {
        try { File.Delete(item[0, i]); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show(_this, String.Format("Error while accessing {0}\n{1}"
                , item[0, i], ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel
                , MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.Retry)
            { i--; }
        }
    }
}
```

...and this code in the main UI thread:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    AnotherClass.Blah(this);
}
```

When I execute this code, I get the unsafe cross-thread exception.  What's the safe way to do this operation?

Comment: Which line of code creates the cross-thread access exception? What type of object is `item`?

Comment: Does the line MessageBox.Show(...) cause the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not condoning the design, but you can pass in the Form to Blah() and then Invoke() against the referenced form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        SomeClass AnotherClass = new SomeClass();
        AnotherClass.Blah(this);
    }

    private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }

}

public class SomeClass
{
    public void Blah(Form frm)
    {
        int item_quantity = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < item_quantity; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                //File.Delete(item[0, i]);

                Console.WriteLine("i = " + i.ToString());
                throw new Exception("duh");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                frm.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(frm, String.Format("Error while accessing {0}\n{1}", "something", ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        if (result == DialogResult.Retry)
                        {
                            i--;
                        }
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't know how to use the Invoke function LOL!
Thank you very much! Your code works like charm! =))))

Answer (score 2):

> What's the safe way to do this operation?

There is no real safe way to do this.  The message box pops out of nowhere, without any direct connection to a command that the user gave.  One failure mode is that the user continues working with your UI, clicking the mouse or pressing the space bar.  And your message box pops up a millisecond before he clicked the mouse or pressed a key.  He'll never see the message.

So something was supposed to be done, it didn't get done and the user is completely unaware of it.  Not a good thing.  You'll need to doctor your UI so this condition can never occur.  Clearly that will require that you do error reporting a different way than by using a temporary message box.  Many possible alternatives of course, could be as simple as a Label that reports state.  StatusStrip is good for this.

The actual exception is a bogus one.  It is triggered by the built-in diagnostics that checks that code uses UI in a thread-safe way.  The underlying winapi call is GetParent(), one of the very few user32 Windows functions that can safely be called, and used, from a worker thread.  The only legitimate reason I know where using Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls to work around the problem is okay.  But fix the real problem instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do UI work on a background thread, hence the cross-thread exception. [`RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.aspx) has a property called `Error` that will hold any exception that gets thrown by the `RunWorkerAsync` delegate. Set up a handler for `RunWorkerCompleted` on your `BackgroundWorker` and check if the `Error` property has a value. If it does, prompt the `MessageBox` in the handler because you will be on the UI thread at that point. Call the `BackgroundWorker`'s `RunWorkerAsync` method again on the `DialogResult.Retry` scenario.

(You will probably have to tweak your `BackgroundWorker` and `AnotherClass.Blah` to take in the value of `i` to prime your loop condition for that second call to your `BackgroundWorker`. The [`DoWorkEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.doworkeventargs.aspx) has a property called `Argument` that you can use to pass in that value.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute UI code like this when calling it from another thread:

```
// must use invoke because the timer event is running on a separate thread
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
     MessageBox.Show("Message");
}));
```